# OrbitControls Undefined in Angular2 and Three.js

Tags: javascript, angular, three.js

I'm unable to get OrbitControls working in my Angular2 application. I was successful in displaying a scene with a box but I'm unable to move the camera.

I discovered that my OrbitComponent (which defines orbit controls) is returning a `undefined` value.

**orbit.component.ts**

```
import { Directive, Input } from '@angular/core';

import * as THREE from 'three';
import { OrbitControls } from 'three-orbit-controls';

@Directive({ selector: 'three-orbit-controls' })
export class OrbitControlsComponent {

    @Input() enabled: boolean = true;

    controls: OrbitControls;

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log("hello");
    }

    setupControls(camera, renderer) {
        this.controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
        this.controls.enabled = this.enabled;
    }

    updateControls(scene, camera) {
        this.controls.update();
    }
}
```

**renderer.component.ts**

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input, ContentChild, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import * as THREE from 'three';

import { OrbitControlsComponent } from './controls/orbit.component';

@Directive({ selector: 'three-renderer' })
export class RendererComponent {

    @ContentChild(OrbitControlsComponent) orbitComponent: OrbitControlsComponent;

    constructor(private element: ElementRef) { }

    ngAfterContentInit() {
        console.log("orbitComponent undefined?", this.orbitComponent === undefined);
        // TODO: OrbitControls is NULL!
        if (this.orbitComponent) {
            this.orbitComponent.setupControls(this.camera, this.renderer);
        }

        this.render();
    }
}
```

How can I return an OrbitComponent object?

Answer (score 1):

Directives and components are almost the same in Angular2, but they have differences.

For me is easier handle the renderer as a component, with a template. This will make you able to access your nested elements as you are trying to do with annotations on attributes.

Here you have a sample of the renderer:

```
declare var THREE: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-three-renderer',
  template: `
  <app-three-scene
    [renderer]="renderer">
  </app-three-scene>
  `
})
export class RendererComponent implements OnChanges, AfterViewInit {

  @Input() height: number;
  @Input() width: number;
  @ViewChild(SceneComponent) sceneComp: SceneComponent;

  renderer: THREE.WebGLRenderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({});

  // ... other stuff
}
```

Here I set the a SceneComponent as direct child of the renderer. The SceneComponent will handle the THREE.scene object, cameras lights and so on.

Nevertheless the most important facts are these suggestions:

1. Make your renderer a Component instead of a Directive
2. Access to your child with the @ViewChild decorator. In my case is a SceneComponent but it can be whatever in yours. Make sure to include the component tag selector in the renderer component template.

I hope this would help you!

Comment: Displaying the scene works for me, I'm having trouble injecting an OrbitControlComponent into the scene.

Comment: Sorry for my delay answer. Could you give me more info?  The process should be the same: tag in the HTML and @ViewChild in your SceneComponent ts file. Don't forget to declare in your module your OrbitControlComponent!